# Multiprocessing with large array in state

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, shared-memory, python-multiprocessing

I've got a Class which stores a large `numpy` array in the state. This is causing `multiprocessing.Pool` to become extremely slow. Here's a MRE:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy
import time
from tqdm import tqdm

class MP(object):
    def __init__(self, mat):
        self.mat = mat

    def foo(self, x):
        time.sleep(1)
        return x*x + self.mat.shape[0]

    def bar(self, arr):
        results = []
        with Pool() as p:
            for x in tqdm(p.imap(self.foo, arr)):
                results.append(x)
        return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = numpy.arange(8)
    mat = numpy.random.random((1,1))
    h = MP(mat)
    res = h.bar(x)
    print(res)
```

I've got 4 cores on CPU, which means that this code should (and does) run in approximately 2 seconds. (The `tqdm` shows the 2 seconds as a progress bar, it's not really necessary to this example). However, in the main program, if I do `mat = numpy.random.random((10000,10000))`, it takes forever to run. I suspect this is because `Pool` is making copies of `mat` for each worker, but I'm not sure how this works because `mat` is in the state of the Class, and not directly involved in the `imap` call. So, my questions are:

1. Why is this behavior happening? (i.e., how does `Pool` work within a Class? What exactly does it pickle? What copies are made, and what is passed by reference?)
2. What is a viable workaround to this problem?

**Edit**: Modified `foo` to make use of `mat`, which is more representative of my real problem.

Comment: How large is `x` in your main program?

Comment: In your main program, does the function you pass in to `p.imap` need to be a method of `MP`, or can it be an unbound function?

Comment: @JeremyMcGibbon Good point. I guess my example was not a good representation of my real problem. So, the function does need to be a method of `MP`, because the function actually reads from `mat`.

Comment: Then your question 2 does not have an answer, but hopefully I've answered question 1.

Answer (score 1):

If as you say `mat` is not directly involved in the `imap` call, I'm guessing in general the state of `MP` is not used in the `imap` call (if it is, comment below and I'll remove this answer). If that's the case, you should write `foo` as an unbound function instead of as a method of `MP`. The reason `mat` is getting copied right now is because each execution of `foo` needs to be passed in `self`, which contains `self.mat`.

The following executes quickly regardless of the size of mat:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy
import time
from tqdm import tqdm


class MP(object):

    def __init__(self, mat):
        self.mat = mat

    def bar(self, arr):
        results = []
        with Pool() as p:
            for x in tqdm(p.imap(foo, arr)):
                results.append(x)
        return results

def foo(x):
    time.sleep(1)
    return x * x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = numpy.arange(8)
    mat = numpy.random.random((10000, 10000))
    h = MP(mat)
    res = h.bar(x)
    print(res)
```

If `foo` actually does need to be passed `MP` because it actually does need to read from `mat`, then there is no way to avoid sending `mat` to each processor, and your question 2 does not have an answer other than "you can't". But hopefully I've answered your question 1.